# WordPress 5.9 inserting unwanted duotone SVGs and CSS variables

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I've noticed in the recent WordPress update that global CSS variables and SVGs are embeded into the frontend header and footer.

**CSS variables:**
[image]

**SVGs:**
[image]

This is a lot of unwanted junk that we do not need. I'm looking for a way to remove these all together, I can't find anything in the release notes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While writing this question I have stumbled upon the below...

**Removal of CSS variables**

Adding this to your theme will do the job:

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'global-styles' );
} );
```

**Removal of SVGs**

First (if you haven't already) create a `theme.json` file in your theme folder and add the below:

```json
{
  "version": 1,
  "settings": {
    "color": {
      "duotone": null
    }
  }
}
```